# Why can't clickhosue add a JSON column into an existing table?

Tags: clickhouse

I add a JSON column into an existing table, but when i run select from this table, it report an error:
 `DB::Exception: There is no physical column or subcolumn common2 in table: While executing MergeTreeInOrder. (NO_SUCH_COLUMN_IN_TABLE)`

The version I used:
ClickHouse server version 22.8.2 revision 54460
ClickHouse client version 22.8.2.11

First, I create a table with JSON column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test.github_json2
(
    `event_type` String,
    `log_time` DateTime,
    `common` JSON
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(log_time)
ORDER BY tuple()
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

Then i run command `desc github_json2 SETTINGS describe_extend_object_types = 1;` , the result like this:

```
DESCRIBE TABLE github_json2
SETTINGS describe_extend_object_types = 1

Query id: 8db1c510-2b76-401e-8cc9-268507546b08

event_type String


┌─name───────┬─type────────────────┬─default_type─┬─default_expression─┬─comment─┬─codec_expression─┬─ttl_expression─┐
│ event_type │ String              │              │                    │         │                  │                │
│ log_time   │ DateTime            │              │                    │         │                  │                │
│ common     │ Tuple(_dummy UInt8) │              │                    │         │                  │                │
└────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────────────┴────────────────┘

3 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.
```

Everything looks normal so far.

However, when i tried to add an another JSON column in table:

```
alter table github_json2 add column common2 JSON after common;

DESCRIBE TABLE github_json2
SETTINGS describe_extend_object_types = 1

Query id: a4455165-e7d1-4370-a1d3-2b28d9f57d3f

┌─name───────┬─type────────────────┬─default_type─┬─default_expression─┬─comment─┬─codec_expression─┬─ttl_expression─┐
│ event_type │ String              │              │                    │         │                  │                │
│ log_time   │ DateTime            │              │                    │         │                  │                │
│ common     │ Tuple(_dummy UInt8) │              │                    │         │                  │                │
│ common2    │ Object('json')      │              │                    │         │                  │                │
└────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────────────┴────────────────┘

4 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.001 sec.
```

As shown above, the newly added JSON column behaves differently from the JSON column when the table is created. Also, when i run select from this table:

```
SELECT *
FROM github_json2

Query id: 2cd8dc33-eceb-4865-bab9-3a0e2cc40041


0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.005 sec.

Received exception from server (version 22.8.2):
Code: 16. DB::Exception: Received from 10.***.***.***:9000. DB::Exception: There is no physical column or subcolumn common2 in table: While executing MergeTreeInOrder. (NO_SUCH_COLUMN_IN_TABLE)
```

Also, i can't insert values into this table:

```
insert into github_json2 values ('PushEvent', '2023-03-16 10:12:24', null, null);

Query id: 2d03b862-f89d-4df3-90ed-dbec8595f12e

↓ Progress: 0.00 rows, 0.00 B (0.00 rows/s., 0.00 B/s.)
1 row in set. Elapsed: 0.005 sec.

Received exception from server (version 22.8.2):
Code: 49. DB::Exception: Received from 10.***.***.***:9000. DB::Exception: Least common type for object can be deduced only from tuples, but Object('json') given. (LOGICAL_ERROR)
```

Why does this happen? Is there something I did wrong in the process? Or it is not functional enough because of JSON field is still an experimental field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in 22.8

reproduced  in 22.8
https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/03aa993d-655e-4be3-b4e7-9d0f91b617a5

and don't reproduced in latest (22.3)
https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/886a36e4-b4e0-48d2-96b3-18577ace8b39

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It This issue is indeed fixed in the latest release